# Output from XSLT using copy-of adds an extra XML declaration?

Tags: xml, xslt, declaration

I have a piece of XSLT that does a copy-of on all child elements of a parent element based on a parameter...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- Removes the XML tag from begginning of output -->
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <!-- Include external variables / data -->
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="testNS" result-prefix="testNS" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/hostElement/*[position() > 1]" /> 
            <xsl:element name="anotherElement">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//hostElement/childElement[position() > 1])"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

After running this i get this output below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hostElement xmlns=""><?xml version="1.0"?>
<childElement>...
```

The output it gives seems to have an extra XML statement in it and it doesnt validate. Neither does the namespace exist...

Can someone please try and help me?!

Thank you,

Ash.

Comment: Given what you've shown us, `hostElement` shouldn't even be in the output.  Could you show us a bit more of your XSLT?

Comment: Just added it all on there.. Thank you.

Comment: So the output you provided there the result of inserting the XSLT output into a `hostElement` element?  I think what's happening is that the `omit-xml-declaration` is not being followed and that's how you wind up with an extra XML declaration.  This most is likely unrelated to `<xsl:copy-of>` and has something to do with the way you're executing the XSLT.  Could you show us the code you're using to run the XSLT?

Comment: @JLRishe - I am using an application called Cast Iron to do these transformations. I have figured out the answer now, Cast Iron was adding these by default because it couldnt find them in the output given. Simply adding <parentElement></parentElement> fixed it because that is what it was expecting.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I am using an application called Cast Iron to do these transformations. I have figured out the answer now, Cast Iron was adding these by default because it couldnt find them in the output given. Simply adding `<parentElement></parentElement>` fixed it because that is what it was expecting